# How far Kinshasa DRC is tilted away from the solar plane on the summer and winter solstices?

Tags: climate, seasons

I am given examples of this for Brampton (Canada) (43° 41’ latitude)

On the Summer Solstice you do latitude minus the Earth’s axis tilt which is 23° 26’, so 43° 41’ - 23° 26’ = 20° 15’.

On the Winter Solstice you do latitude plus the Earth's axial tilt, so 43.° 41’ + 23° 26’ = 67° 07’.

I found that the latitude of Kinshasa is approximately 4° 19'S but I'm not sure how we would use this information to solve the question. If we would subtract from the Earth axis tilt we would get a negative value, which doesn't make sense to me. From what I know is that the Summer Solstice occurs when the sun is directly over the Tropic of Cancer, which is located at 23.5° latitude. The Winter Solstice occurs when the sun is directly over the Tropic of Capricorn, which is located at 23.5° south of the equator. Kinshasa is located in the tropic of Capricorn. So can you help me understand how to calculate these?

Comment: Some things to bear in mind. In the northern hemisphere, for all latitudes north of the Tropic of Cancer, such as Canada & Europe, the sun will **always** appear in the southern part of the sky. Similarly in the southern hemisphere, for all latitudes south of the Tropic of Capricorn the sun will **always** appear in the northern part of the sky. For both tropical zones, Cancer & Capricorn, *depending on the time of year*, the sun will be in the southern part of the sky, directly above or to the north. ...

Comment: ... Also, when the northern hemisphere has its summer solstice the southern hemisphere has its winter solstice. While Canadians & Europeans might be dreaming of a white Christmas, Australians are looking forward to spending Christmas on the beach keeping cool.

Answer (score 2):

A simple diagram may help to explain the calculations. 23° 26' is the north and south latitudes where the Sun is overhead on the solstices. The angles that you give for Brampton Canada are the zenith distance of the Sun; that is, the angle between the point overhead (the zenith) and the Sun at noon.
[image: sun's position]

- For summer at Brampton, A = 43° 41' - 23° 26' = 20° 15'.
- For winter at Brampton, B = 43° 41' + 23° 26' = 67° 07'. (The Sun is further from the zenith and lower in the sky in winter.)
- For summer at Kinshasa, D = 23° 26' - 4° 19' = 19° 07'.
- For winter at Kinshasa, C = 23° 26' + 4° 19' = 27° 45'. (The Sun is further from the zenith and lower in the sky in winter.)